# How to add egg files and import modules in python?

Tags: python, hive, python-module

How do we import modules from egg file in python? I have to import modules from lxml.egg and need to add it as a package to the transform script (in python) for running a map reduce job. I tried adding the egg file to sys.path and then importing it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the path to the egg file at the beginning of `sys.path` so that you can make sure the module you want to import is not masked by others in `sys.path`.